# Getting FirebaseDatabse value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am new at firebase and I do not know how to get the score value in the image below which is in a push and a auth id, I have been trying to solve this problem but the app just crashes, can someone tell me how to get the score value? please

```
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_classes, container, false)

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    var myRef = database?.getReference("Users")

    myRef?.child(mAuth?.currentUser!!.uid)?.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val score = p0.child("score")
                Toast.makeText((context as AppCompatActivity).applicationContext, score.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText((context as AppCompatActivity).applicationContext, p0.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })


    return view
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my answer, this should be working.

```
myRef?.child(mAuth?.currentUser!!.uid)?.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                //val score = p0.child("score")
                snapshot?.children?.forEach { // loop for nodes
                val map = dataSnapshot.value as HashMap<String, Any>?
                    if(map!!.containsKey("score")){ // check weathrer score variable is contains
                       var score = map["score"]
                       //break :- if you do not want any oporation 
                    }
                    Toast.makeText((context as AppCompatActivity).applicationContext, score.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText((context as AppCompatActivity).applicationContext, p0.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
```

Comment: I wonder why do you comment the val score = p0.child("score")?

Comment: I forgot to remove that comment. its useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataSnapshot` can have multiple children, so you need to loop over `p0.children` to get each individual child node.

```
myRef?.child(mAuth?.currentUser!!.uid)?.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            snapshot?.children?.forEach {
                val score = it.child("score")
                Toast.makeText((context as AppCompatActivity).applicationContext, score.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

The `it` used in here is a reference to the current child in the `forEach` loop.

Comment: this works but is has an issue that at the end it retrieves null because the orher push does not have score value